# How to Design a React Native Architecture with Bottom Tabs and a Right-Side Drawer Accessible from All Views?

Tags: react-native

I am working on a React Native app and have some specific requirements regarding the navigation architecture. I would like to implement the following features:

```
Bottom navigation tabs that should be visible across all views. For these tabs, I want to use createMaterialTopTabNavigator from the @react-navigation/material-top-tabs library.

A right-side navigation drawer that can be opened via a button in the header. This button should also be accessible from all views.

Every view accessed via the drawer should also retain the bottom navigation tabs and the button to open the drawer in the header.
```

I am struggling to find the best way to structure this. Has anyone done something similar or have suggestions on how to implement this architecture?

Thank you in advance for your help!